# The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspeleld or missing

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I appologize if something like this has already been posted or is just a simple fix but I've been looking around all over and can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I'm using vba: ms access, and I'm trying to comapre two identical tables in diffrent databases by running a query. I've been trying to make the script so it can be run on diffrent databases requiring only user input. However throught this process I seem to keep getting an error that reads:

> The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
>   is misspelled or missing.

The LinkUserTable function basically creates a linked table from another DB based off user input. Below is the subroutine:

```
Sub LinkTables()
        Dim sTable1 As String
        Dim sTable2 As String
    sTable1 = LinkUserTable
    sTable2 = LinkUserTable

    vars_sql = "SELECT " & sTable1 & ".[f_ptid]," & sTable1 & ".[f_flag]," & sTable1 & ".[f_user]," & sTable1 & ".[f_brief]," & sTable1 & ".[f_gid]," & sTable1 & ".[f_vco]," & sTable1 & ".[f_dtype]," & sTable1 & ".[f_precs]," & sTable1 & ".[f_addr]," & sTable1 & ".[f_ndim]," & sTable1 & ".[f_sys]," & sTable1 & ".[f_unit]," & sTable1 & ".[f_value]," & sTable1 & ".[f_pred]," & sTable1 & ".[f_bflag]," & sTable1 & ".[f_dim1]," & sTable1 & ".[f_dim2]," & sTable1 & ".[f_dim3]," & sTable1 & ".[f_bound]," & sTable1 & ".[f_size]," & sTable1 & ".[f_updat]," & sTable1 & ".[f_time]," & sTable1 & ".[f_ldes]," & sTable1 & ".[f_sflag]," & sTable1 & ".[f_tflag]," & sTable1 & ".[rid]" + _
                    "FROM" + sTable1 + " AS LEFT JOIN " + sTable2 + " AS ON sTable1.[f_ptid] = sTable2.[f_ptid]" + _
                    "WHERE (((" & sTable2 & ".[f_ptid]) Is Null))" 


If CheckQuery("new_old") = "Yes" Then
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "new_old"
        End If

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("new_old", vars_sql)

End Sub
```

I was just wondering based off of this what the possible problems could be that would cause this error? All of the fields are in both databases, all with the same properties(just diffrent data). I appologize if there is a lack of information I can supply more if needed.

Comment: Was `misspeleld` deliberately misspelled for irony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `LEFT JOIN`, not `AS LEFT JOIN`.

The exception to this would be if you want to give the tables an alias, in which case, you'd do `AS Alias LEFT JOIN`... however, you *don't* want to do that in this case, since you are using `[table].[columnname]` syntax).

Comment: Just as I feared a simple fix. Thanks! Appreciate it! Still pretty new to SQL and don't have a lot of places to ask for specific help.

Answer (score 0):

The second line for the `vars_sql` assignment has some table variables inside of the string:

```
" AS ON sTable1.[f_ptid] = sTable2.[f_ptid]"
```

The above should look like:

```
" AS ON " + sTable1 + ".[f_ptid] = " + sTable2 + ".[f_ptid]"
```

Comment: Well, looks like we're both right; I missed the `" AS ON sTable1.[f_ptid] = sTable2.[f_ptid]"`, but you've still got the alias syntax errors.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - sounds like we're both *partially* right. You made a good catch on the `LEFT JOIN` syntax.